How to run Javascript API built with yarn and babel in supervisord
I have APIs in Javascript using the following structure:
src
   app
   .babelrc
   index.js
package.json


app contains the source files.


.babelrc

{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}


index.js

import '@babel/polyfill'; // always first import
import 'dotenv/config'; // always second import
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

import fooRoute from './app/route/fooRoute';

const app = express();

// Add middleware for parsing URL encoded bodies (which are usually sent by browser)
app.use(cors());
// Add middleware for parsing JSON and urlencoded data and populating `req.body`
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/', fooRoute);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, '127.0.0.1').on('listening', () => {
    console.log(`${(new Date()).toISOString()} are live on ${process.env.PORT}`);
});

export default app;


package.json

{
    "name": "foo_api",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "babel src -d dist"
    },
    "author": "Guilherme Alan Ritter",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.23.4",
        "@babel/core": "^7.23.6",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.6",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "pg": "^8.7.1",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2"
    }
}

I'm using supervisord to manage the API processes. I'm using the following configuration:

/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                      ; sockef file mode (default 0700)
chown=guir:guir                 ; socket file uid:gid owner

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf


/etc/supervisor/conf.d/foo_api.conf

[program:FooAPI]
command=env --chdir /home/guir/api/FooAPI/ /home/guir/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/node /home/guir/api/FooAPI/dist/index.js
user=guir
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/guir/log/Foo/api.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10

And then I have configured nginx to redirect calls from my domain to the ports listening to each project, but that's not relevant for this question.
Now I'm facing issues with running npm on my VPS (lack of resources, I think). I've had success with migrating to yarn but only for the front-end projects.
For the back-end projects, I've done the following changes:

In package.json, I've added "packageManager": "yarn@4.5.0".
Just to be sure, I've created an empty .yarnrc.yml file to make it clear that I do not want the node_modules folder anymore.
Now there are .pnp.cjs, .pnp.loader.mjs and yarn.lock files in the project root folder.

The supervisord config was changed to the following:

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/foo_api.conf

[program:FooAPI]
directory=/home/guir/api/FooAPI
command=yarn node /home/guir/api/FooAPI/dist/index.js
user=guir
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/guir/log/Foo/api.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10

If I do this, yarn can't be found. I tried instead:
[program:FooAPI]
directory=/home/guir/api/FooAPI
command=/home/guir/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/yarn node /home/guir/api/FooAPI/dist/index.js
user=guir
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/guir/log/Foo/api.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10

Now node can't be found. Naturally, I tried the following:
[program:FooAPI]
directory=/home/guir/api/FooAPI
command=/home/guir/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/yarn /home/guir/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/node /home/guir/api/FooAPI/dist/index.js
user=guir
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/guir/log/Foo/api.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10

However, when I do this, yarn runs on the provided folder but it looks like it tries to install dependencies on that folder instead of running node to run my file.
I've searched and found out that node in that case is a yarn command and not an executable. I've tried some different combinations of using quotes but either it can't find some part of the command or it runs yarn as I described before.
I think it is supervisord that does some preprocessing on that command and changes the way it's interpreted later on. I also tried to invoke bash or sh to run that command but then it is bash which can't find yarn, even after sourcing ~/.bashrc.
All of these commands I tested by running them in the terminal. Some of them work as expected, but not as a supervisord command.
What is needed to make supervisord run projects built with yarn and babel?
Thanks in advance.
